# Calculating percentages for multiple numeric variables by a group variable

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage, reshape2

I am trying to compute Percentage of a column where depending on Unique category as shown in Image .
[image]

As we can see in the image where `Tag` is One Column and `Long` is the other Column. so Here we want Percentage calculation for `Long` column  Based on the `Unique Tag No`. In one of the example for all `Tag=1` and the values in `Long` Column `1004 is 0.42%` and `544 is 0.22%` and `545 is 0.22%`  and `282 is 0.11%` and `1 is 0.00%` of `Total` 2376. Similarly for every `Tag` and percentage calculation for other Columns such as `Medium` , `Short`, `Urgent` is to be Done.

```
df <- data.frame(Tag = c(1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,2 ,2),
       YPred = c("L1", "L2" ,"L3", "L4", "L5", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5"),
       Long = c(1004 , 544 , 545 , 282  ,  1 ,2068 ,3006 ,3711 ,2342 ,  33),
       Medium = c(108, 252, 211, 149,   0,  17, 110, 248, 341,   4),
       short = c(58, 118, 131,  73,   4,   0,  43, 150, 189,2),
       Urgent = c(5, 70, 65, 24 , 5 ,22 ,18, 31 ,96,  2))
```

Here the Expected Output is the Image output written in Color. Thank you

Comment: You have not provided any code that you have tried yourself so far. Also I don't see any desired output in more detail - you want to replace the existing columns, add addtional columns, do you want the totals being printed and where...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to handle your task. You group the data by `Tag`. Then, you want to do the calculation you described for the four columns (i.e., `Long`, `Medium`, `short`, and `Urgent`). Your are dividing each value in each group with the sum of the values for each group in `mutate_at()`.

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, Tag) %>%
mutate_at(.vars = vars(Long:Urgent),
          .funs = funs(. / sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))

#     Tag  YPred         Long      Medium       short     Urgent
#   <dbl> <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1     1     L1 0.4225589226 0.150000000 0.151041667 0.02958580
# 2     1     L2 0.2289562290 0.350000000 0.307291667 0.41420118
# 3     1     L3 0.2293771044 0.293055556 0.341145833 0.38461538
# 4     1     L4 0.1186868687 0.206944444 0.190104167 0.14201183
# 5     1     L5 0.0004208754 0.000000000 0.010416667 0.02958580
# 6     2     L1 0.1853046595 0.023611111 0.000000000 0.13017751
# 7     2     L2 0.2693548387 0.152777778 0.111979167 0.10650888
# 8     2     L3 0.3325268817 0.344444444 0.390625000 0.18343195
# 9     2     L4 0.2098566308 0.473611111 0.492187500 0.56804734
#10     2     L5 0.0029569892 0.005555556 0.005208333 0.01183432
```

Comment: i am getting error of `argument ".cols" is missing ,with no default` when i execute above code inside Shiny enviorment. if in r enoirment it is running perfectly fine But in shiny enviornment it is giving error as specified ,guide me on this.